# How to convert hex numbers to byte string?

Tags: javascript

```
> str = '\xae\xee'
'®î'
```

How to convert [0xae, 0xee] to '®î'?

Comment: hope this link help for you https://gist.github.com/tauzen/3d18825ae41ff3fc8981

Comment: sorry, not tested String.fromCharCode, I thought it can only handle numbers less than 128

Comment: actually I tested String.fromCharCode(128), it is ' ', gave me that wrong expectation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode()` to convert the hex values to their string representation with `.map()` and `.join()` to form a string:

```js
const hex = [0xae, 0xee];
const res = hex.map(s => String.fromCharCode(s)).join('');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @georg ah nice, very clean

Comment: strange, '®\u0000\u0000î\u0001\u0000'

Comment: @thinker with what input?

Comment: > [0xae, 0xee].map(String.fromCharCode).join('');
'®\u0000\u0000î\u0001\u0000'

Comment: @thinker3 I think doing `String.fromCharCode(...[0xae, 0xee])` will work if you are running this in node

Comment: @thinker3 the reason why `.map()` isn't working here is because `.map()` will pass through the index as the second argument for `String.fromCharCode()`. We need to explicitly call it (`.map(x => String.fromCharCode(x))`) - I've updated my code